# What is the value of the mass gap in QCD?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, simulations, quantum-chromodynamics

Is there any estimation either from experiments or numerical simulations for the value of the mass gap in QCD?

Comment: relevant answers here  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9704/

Comment: Thanks @annav. Lubos' answer tells about theories that support evidences for the existence of the gap mass. But I would like to know whether any of these theories give some numerical value for this gap.

Answer (score 1):

As Lubos says in his [answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9704/), there are theoretical proposals fo the mass gap in lattice QCD and other theoretical models.

Searching for "lattice QCD and the mass gap" [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0511173v7) came up, and they do give a formula for the mass gap (number 22), but in dimensionless numbers!!

It is not  a simple concept in the QCD frame.